# Haskell not finding "indirect" type

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm taking a compilers class, and I decided to do it in haskell, but I'm having a hard time setting up the ast. My issue is that I have an `Atom` class and an `Expr` class and one instance of the `Expr` can be an `Atom`, but when the `Expr` is immediately an Atom it has an issue. Here is the example:

```
data Atom -- cannot be reduced farther
    = Const Int -- int is value
    | Var String -- string is name
    deriving (Show) -- So we can print it

data Expr -- add input and the like
    = Add Expr Expr -- add is two exprs
    | USub Expr -- negation
    | Input -- call to input
    | Atomic Atom -- or an atomic
    deriving (Show) -- So we can print it

data Statement
    = Print Expr
    | Discard Expr
    | Assign String Expr
    deriving (Show) -- So we can print it


main = do 
    let test5 = Print (Const 2)
    putStrLn $ show test5
```

The compiler fails on the `Print (Const 2)` because it expected an Expr. Is there a fix to this, and is there better vocabular for expressing this problem?

Comment: How about `Print (Atomic (Const 2))`?

Comment: It _may_ be convenient to define `IsString Atom` and `Num Atom` instances (with the second one only working in the `Const` case). Then, `Print (Atomic 2)` would work, and so would `Print (Atomic "hi")`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson That works. Want to aswer so I can accept it and give you the cred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Const 2` is an `Atom`, but `Print` takes an `Expr` as an argument. Luckily, every `Atom` can be made into an `Expr` with the `Atomic` constructor. So:

```
main = do
    let test5 = Print (Atomic (Const 2))
    print test5
```